# How to find $\ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T : P_3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(p(x)) = \begin{bmatrix}p(1)\\p(2)\\p(3)\end{bmatrix}$. 
>   Show that $T$ is a linear transformation, and find $\ker(T)$. $P_3$ := {$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 | a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \in \mathbb{R}$}

I know that $T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w)$ and $cT(v) = T(cv)$ to prove it's a linear transformation.  Am I just substituting $v$ and $w$ in the $p(x)$ equations?

And I'm really stuck on how to solve for the kernel.  I know that it is like the nullspace but it there a different way to solve for it since it is for a linear transformation? I'm slightly confused on what I'm trying to manipulate.

Comment: What have you tried, can you show us your work? Begin by definition. Regarding kernel, can you tell what kind of elements of $P_3$ have $1,2$  and $3$ as zeros?

Comment: "*Am I just substituting $v$ and $w$ in the $p(x)$ equations?*"  If by substituting, you mean looking at $p(v)$ and $p(w)$, then no.  Rather, keep in mind what the *deeper meaning* of the whole $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ is.  That is to say, here, the transformation applied to the sum of vectors from our space is equal to the sum of the transformations of each vector separately.  Letting $v$ and $w$ each be polynomials, that would be written exactly as before., which if you prefer can be written as $T(v(x)+w(x))=T(v(x))+T(w(x))$

Comment: As for how to find the kernel of a transformation., as always it is the set of all elements in our vector space such that when the transformation is applied to it results in the "zero" vector of our codomain.  If you insist, you could do this exactly as you normally do with finding the kernels of matrices using row reduction and similar techniques, but you should find that there is little reason to here.

Comment: @user133929 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The kernel is made of all polynomials in $P_3$ that have $1$, $2$, and $3$ as roots. For example $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is an element in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

To check for the LT let consider

- $T(p(x)+q(x)) =
     \begin{bmatrix}p(1)+q(1)\\p(2)+q(2)\\p(3)+q(3)\end{bmatrix}=?$
- $T(c\cdot p(x)) = \begin{bmatrix}c\cdot p(1)\\c\cdot p(2)\\c\cdot p(3)\end{bmatrix}=?$

For the second part, you can proceed exactly for the ordinary vector space, let consider that each polynomial in the form $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ in the basis $\cal B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is represented by its components $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Answer (score 0):

As @ir7 suggests, if $p \in \ker T$ then

$$\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} = T(p) = \pmatrix{p(1) \\ p(2) \\ p(3)} \implies p(1) = p(2) = p(3) = 0 \implies (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \text{ divides } p$$

Therefore, $$\ker T = \operatorname{span}\{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\} = \{\alpha (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) : \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$T(p(x)) = \begin{bmatrix}p(1)\\p(2)\\p(3)\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} $$

$$p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=0$$

$$ p(x)=a(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$

That is $$ Ker(T)=\{p(x): p(x)=a(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\}$$